# Android studio, pick picture form files, pictures are grey out

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have managed to get some code working for picking a pictures from mobile stored files to the imageView, but I am not sure why all the images files are grey out, and I cannot select them.

I have searched for a solution, but I couldn't find anything, so any advice will be appreciated.

methods for selecting a picture:

```
 public void chooseImage (View objectView){
        try {
            Intent objectIntent = new Intent();
            objectIntent.setType("iv_addBday/*");

            objectIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(objectIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
        try {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
                imageFilePath = data.getData();
                imageToStore = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageFilePath);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(imageToStore);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsJzu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about :

```
 public void chooseImage (View objectView){
        try {
            Intent objectIntent = new Intent();
            objectIntent.setType("image/*");

            objectIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(objectIntent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }
```